# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml

I have searched 'Similar questions' suggestions on this, but cannot find a match.

Code works fine using standard JS. The problem has only emerged when I refactored my code using JQuery. I'm now getting this DOMException error. The stack trace points to the ***htmlTableStructure*** variable in the ***responseHandler*** function, and the error suggests the markup is invalid XML, but I can't spot any obvious errors.

Code attached below. Can anyone help?

**Stack Trace**

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': The provided markup is invalid XML, and therefore cannot be inserted into an XML document.
    at buildFragment (http://localhost:8080/Section5_AjaxJS_war_exploded/resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.js:5032:19)
    at Function.jQuery.parseHTML (http://localhost:8080/Section5_AjaxJS_war_exploded/resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.js:10337:11)
    at new jQuery.fn.init (http://localhost:8080/Section5_AjaxJS_war_exploded/resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.js:3167:33)
    at jQuery (http://localhost:8080/Section5_AjaxJS_war_exploded/resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.js:157:10)
    at responseHandler (http://localhost:8080/Section5_AjaxJS_war_exploded/resources/js/jquery_utils.js:23:30)
    at Object.success (http://localhost:8080/Section5_AjaxJS_war_exploded/resources/js/jquery_utils.js:12:13)
    at fire (http://localhost:8080/Section5_AjaxJS_war_exploded/resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.js:3496:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost:8080/Section5_AjaxJS_war_exploded/resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.js:3626:7)
    at done (http://localhost:8080/Section5_AjaxJS_war_exploded/resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.js:9786:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/Section5_AjaxJS_war_exploded/resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.js:10047:9)
```

**Webform**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Film Search</title>
    <script
            src="resources/js/jquery_utils.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" bgcolor="#20b2aa">
        <tr><th><big></big>Film Search Application</th></tr>
    </table>
<p/>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Retrieve Data from GetAllFilms</legend>
        <form action="#">
            <input type="button" value="XML" onclick="getAllFilms('GetAllFilms', 'xml')"/>
            <input type="button" value="JSON" onclick="getAllFilms('GetAllFilms', 'json')"/>
            <input type="button" value="TEXT" onclick="getAllFilms('GetAllFilms', 'text')"/>
        </form>
        <p/>
        <div id="getallfilms"></div>
    </fieldset><br></br>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript Onclick Function**

```
function getAllFilms(servletAddress, dataFormat) {
    $.ajax({

        url: servletAddress,                                
        type: "POST",                                       
        dataType : dataFormat,                              
        data : {format : dataFormat},                       

        success: function(servletResponse) {                
            responseHandler(servletResponse, dataFormat);   
        }
    });
}
```

**Javascript Response Handler Function**

```
function responseHandler(servletResponse, dataFormat) {

    // create base table structure object, with headings
    let htmlTableStructure = $(
        "<table border='1' class='ajaxTable'>" +
        "<tr>" +
            "<th>Film Id</th>" +
            "<th>Name</th>" +
            "<th>Year</th>" +
            "<th>Director</th>" +
            "<th>Cast</th>" +
            "<th>Plot</th>" +
        "</tr>"
    );

    // if data format passed in is json
    if (dataFormat === "json") {

        // append rows to html table structure
        $.each(servletResponse.films, function(i, filmObject) {
            htmlTableStructure.append("<tr>");
            $.each(filmObject, function(key, value){
                htmlTableStructure.append("<td>" + value + "</td>")
            })
            htmlTableStructure.append("</tr>");
        });

    // if data format passed in is xml
    } else if (dataFormat === "xml") {

        // append rows to html table structure
        // loop through each film node in xml & get child node values
        $(servletResponse).find('film').each(function () {
            htmlTableStructure.append("" +
                "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).find('id').text() + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).find('title').text() + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).find('year').text() + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).find('director').text() + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).find('stars').text() + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + $(this).find('review').text() + "</td>" +
                "</tr>"
            );
        });

    // if data format passed in is text
    } else {

        // append rows to html table structure

        // split servlet response into rows using $ delimiter (rows 3 & 10)
        // ignore first row (this is the header, which we've already hardcoded)
        let rowString = servletResponse.split("$").slice(1);

        // then for each remaining row, split into fields by # delimiter and wrap row in <tr>
        $.each(rowString, function (i, stringLine) {
            htmlTableStructure.append(
                    "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + stringLine.split('#') + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>"
            );
        })

    } $("#getallfilms").append(htmlTableStructure + "</table>");
}
```

Comment: You're treating `htmlTableStructure` as a string.  Rather than use `htmlTableStructure = $("<table>"); htmlTableStructure .append("<tr><td></td></tr>")` just keep it as a string: `htmlTableStructure = "<table>"; htmlTableStructure += "<tr><td></td></tr>"; htmlTableStructure += "</table>"; $("#getall").append(htmlTableStructure);`  - but you're then responsible to put closing tags in the right place - so it's generally *safer* to build nodes and append to them - just don't treat them as a string.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to append content to invalid markup. You first create a `<table>` but don't close it. The `.append(...)` method in jQuery appends content to the end of a DOM node.

This kind of stuff `.append(htmlTableStructure + "</table>");` is not correct.

You'll need to continue refactoring your code to make it compatible. Might be a good idea to review how jQuery's append method works: https://api.jquery.com/append/

For example:

```
htmlTableStructure = $("<table></table>");
htmlTableStructure.append("<tr><th>...</th>...</tr>");
htmlTableStructure.append("<tr><td>...</td>...</tr>");
```

Comment: thanks for your responses. I think I've slightly misunderstand how .append works. it does now work following @freedomn-m method. but I guess that's no longer using append.

Comment: In my case, the error was simply caused by unclosed `<input>` (vs `<input />`) in the HTML I was attempting to append. Bottomline: Thoroughly scour the HTML you're attempting to append to make sure it's 100% valid, even if the same HTML code "worked" in other circumstances.